# Unity keypress not registering

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Before I start I should mention I am a unity noob.

So I have been following a pong tutorial,but I have a problem. The rackets are not moving when you press the arrow. If you know how to fix this please let me know

My code:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class MoveRacket : MonoBehaviour {
// up and down keys (to be set in the Inspector)
public KeyCode up;
public KeyCode down;

void FixedUpdate () {
    // up key pressed?
    if (Input.GetKey(up)) {
        transform.Translate(new Vector2(0.0f, 0.1f));
    }

    // down key pressed?
    if (Input.GetKey(down)) {
        transform.Translate(new Vector2(0.0f, -0.1f));
    }
}
}
```

and the control picking option:
[image: What shows up when I add the script in the inspector]

Comment: do you actually assign up and down from the comboboxes?

Comment: Duplicate question #http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26318390/key-input-wont-work-in-unity/26318448?noredirect=1#comment41302388_26318448
Don't ask questions twice... if you can't find your answer then just wait for some hours and after that try it again or ask it in the chat : http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/37624/unity3d-developers

Answer (score 0):

You said it doesn't move when you press the arrow. According to your key code assignments, you should press `W` or `S`.

Comment: no, I have two rackets one that is controlled with w s and one with the arrows

Comment: Are you sure you're attaching the scripts to the objects in the scene? I can't think of another reason this happens. It's working for me.

Answer (score 0):

```
just change the name of your method FxedUpdate() to Update()

using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class MoveRacket : MonoBehaviour {
// up and down keys (to be set in the Inspector)
public KeyCode up;
public KeyCode down;

void Update () {
// up key pressed?
if (Input.GetKey(up)) {
    transform.Translate(new Vector2(0.0f, 0.1f));
}

// down key pressed?
if (Input.GetKey(down)) {
    transform.Translate(new Vector2(0.0f, -0.1f));
}
}
}
```

Comment: Why should OP do that? For input `FixedUpdate()` and `Update()` don't change much.

Answer (score 0):

The real solution so that you don't make mistakes in the *Unity Editor*.

```
void FixUodate()
{
    if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.UpArrow))  
       transform.Translate(new Vector2(0.0f, 0.1f));


    else if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.DownArrow))  
      transform.Translate(new Vector2(0.0f, -0.1f));
}
```