# Key input won't work in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have been following a pong tutorial, but I have a problem.

The rackets are not moving when you press the arrow.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class MoveRacket : MonoBehaviour
{
    // up and down keys (to be set in the Inspector)
    public KeyCode up;
    public KeyCode down;

    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        // up key pressed?
        if (Input.GetKey(up))
        {
            transform.Translate(new Vector2(0.0f, 0.1f));
        }

        // down key pressed?
        if (Input.GetKey(down))
        {
            transform.Translate(new Vector2(0.0f, -0.1f));
        }
    }
}
```

And I assigned the images a key in the inspector.

Comment: Have you tried debugging inside the ifs? Try printing something there to see if it enters the conditions or not.

Answer (score 0):

Okay so what you need to check is if the KeyCode is defined in your project settings.

Its best to use something like the following code to detect such key presses :

```
void Update () {
    if (Input.GetButton("Fire1") && Time.time > nextFire) {
        nextFire = Time.time + fireRate;
        Instantiate(projectile, transform.position, transform.rotation);
    }
}
```

Source : http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input.GetButton.html
Also I recommend watching the following tutorial : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JgY5YxNHxtw
It explains it all very clearly.

Hope it helped you ;)

EDIT : Changed the function to void as it seems like you are using C#

Comment: I updated it ;) check the video I'm sure it will help.

Answer (score 0):

I think I get you. You dont need to assign the Keycodes in the inspector. You can access them directly from the script. It should simplify your script.

Instead of this:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class MoveRacket : MonoBehaviour
{
    // up and down keys (to be set in the Inspector)
    public KeyCode up;
    public KeyCode down;

    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        // up key pressed?
        if (Input.GetKey(up))
        {
            transform.Translate(new Vector2(0.0f, 0.1f));
        }

        // down key pressed?
        if (Input.GetKey(down))
        {
            transform.Translate(new Vector2(0.0f, -0.1f));
        }
    }
}
```

Try this:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class MoveRacket : MonoBehaviour
{
        public float speed = 30f;
         //the speed at which you move at. Value can be changed if you want 

    void Update()
    {
        // up key pressed?
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.W)
        {
            transform.Translate(Vector2.up * speed * time.deltaTime, Space.world);
        }

        // down key pressed?
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.S))
        {
            transform.Translate(Vector2.down * speed * time.deltaTime, Space.World);
        }
    }
}
```

Assuming you want to use wasd keys for movement. You can add additional ones using an OR modifier (||) if you want. Also, for the second player, be sure to change the keycodes, or both paddles will move at the same time.

CODE EXPLANATION:
the speed variable is what speed you want to move at. Change it as per your needs.

in transfor.Translate(), you want to move up, at a constant speed, over time, in world coordinates (not local). That is why you use Vector2.up * speed * time.deltaTime. Vector2.up is the same as

```
new Vector2 (0f, 1f);
```

you multiply it by speed to get the distance to move, and then by Time.deltaTime  to get the distance to move in this frame. Since Update is called every frame, you will move the distance every frame.

In moving down, Vector2.down is the same as

```
new Vector2(0f, -1f);
```

Hope this helped!